# Descomponer un dataframe en varios dataframes, uno por cada columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Dispongo de un dataframe df con la siguiente estructura

```
            Acatis  Avantage  TrueValue  ValorRelativo
Date                                                  
2014-07-31  199.08      10.0      10.22         11.631
2014-08-04  198.79      10.0      10.19         11.616
2014-08-05  198.59      10.0      10.17         11.614
```

Necesito hacer, con cada columna, un dataframe cuyo nombre sea el nombre de la columna y que tenga por nombre de la única columna "Close".
Cada uno de estos dataframes tienen que tener esta estructura.

```
             Close
Date              
2014-07-31  199.08
2014-08-04  198.79
2014-08-05  198.59
```

Puedo hacer lo siguiente:

```
acatis = df[["Acatis"]].rename (columns = {"Acatis":"Close"})
```

pero me soluciona el problema en parte solamente, porque el nombre del dataframe nuevo, acatis en este ejemplo, lo tengo que escribir, es decir, no lo asocia por defecto de alguna manera. En cada ejecución del programa, puedo seleccionar otra lista que dará lugar a otros nombres diferentes y tendría que modificar los nombres de estos nuevos df. 
He intentado con pivot(), stack(), y unstack() y no acabo de encontra la solución.
¿Cual puede ser la forma más sencilla de hacerlo.?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente lo que buscas es crear variables de forma dinámica, esto es posible en Python, aunque no es generalmente recomendable:

- Usando [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

  ```
  for col in df.columns:
      exec(f'{col} = df[["{col}"]].rename(columns={{"{col}": "Close"}})')
  ```

  `exec` simplemente recibe una cadena que sea código Python válido y la ejecuta. Solo tenemos que formatear la cadena adecuadamente.
- Usando directamente los diccionarios [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) o `locals` dependiendo del espacio de nombres donde queramos crear las variables:

  ```
  for col in df.columns:
      globals()[col] = df[[col]].rename(columns={col: "Close"})
  ```

  Con ello has creado una variable por cada columna, con el mismo nombre que la columna,  que hace referencia al nuevo DataFrame correspondiente:

  > ```
  > >>> Acatis
  >              Close
  > Date              
  > 2014-07-31  199.08
  > 2014-08-04  198.79
  > 2014-08-05  198.59
  > ```

---

> **Por distintas razones (legibilidad, complejidad, peligro intrínseco de modificar variables globales dinámicamente, ...), lo anterior no es recomendable.**

---

- La forma correcta y más comúnmente aceptada de hacer lo que quieres es usar un diccionario, donde las claves sean el identificador de cada DataFrame y el valor el DataFrame:

  ```
  dfs = {col: df[[col]].rename(columns={col: "Close"}) for col in df.columns}
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> dfs["Acatis"]
  >
  >              Close
  > Date              
  > 2014-07-31  199.08
  > 2014-08-04  198.79
  > 2014-08-05  198.59
  > ```
- Si desea acceder a cada DataFrame como si de un atributo se tratara, lo suyo es crear un espacio de nombres propio. Puedes usar una clase que actúe como contenedor, siendo cada DataFrame atributos de la misma o usar [`types.SimpleNamespaces`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

  ```
  from types import SimpleNamespace


  dfs = SimpleNamespace(**{col: df[[col]].rename(columns={col: "Close"}) for col in df.columns})
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> dfs.Acatis
  >
  >              Close
  > Date              
  > 2014-07-31  199.08
  > 2014-08-04  198.79
  > 2014-08-05  198.59
  > ```
- Puedes hacer lo mismo usando una clase como contenedor:

  ```
  class Dfs:
      pass

  dfs = Dfs()

  for col in df.columns:
      setattr(dfs, col, df[[col]].rename(columns={col: "Close"}))
  ```
- Otra solución, dado que usas Pandas, es usar una Serie de Pandas para almacenar los DataFrames:

  ```
  dfs = pd.Series({col: df[[col]].rename(columns={col: "Close"}) for col in df.columns})
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> dfs.Acatis
  >
  >              Close
  > Date              
  > 2014-07-31  199.08
  > 2014-08-04  198.79
  > 2014-08-05  198.59
  > ```

### Nota

Si quieres que el identificador/clave sea en minúsculas (`dfs["acatis"`] / `dfs.acatis`) usa `str.lower`:

```
{col.lower(): df[[col]].rename ...}
```

Comment: Sorprendido por la cantidad de opciones que ofrece Python. Python es muy gratificante. Muchas gracias