# Base de datos en Python

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas

deseo hacer una base de datos con archivos de excel, mi duda empezo desde querer asignar variables a cada uno de estos archivos. Comparto mi codigo para leer el archivo de excel en pandas.

```
datos=pd.read_excel(open('C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Programa peaje\\MAYO 2019.xlsx', 'rb'))
```

Todos los archivos estan nombrados de esa manera (mes y año), mi pregunta es si puedo crear un bucle que me declare variables con los nombres de los archivos. Tengo pensado algo como esto de manera ilustrativa

```
for archivo.nombre in programa peaje:
    nombre= pd.read_excel(open('C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Programa peaje\\nombre.xlsx', 'rb'))
```

de manera que quede

```
MAYO 2019= pd.read_excel(open('C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Programa peaje\\MAYO 2019.xlsx', 'rb'))
JUNIO 2019=pd.read_excel(open('C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Programa peaje\\JUNIO 2019.xlsx', 'rb'))
JULIO 2019= pd.read_excel(open('C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Programa peaje\\JUNIO 2019.xlsx', 'rb'))
```

Cualquier suguerencia o idea diferente es totalmente agradecida

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Podrías crear una lista antes de entrar al bucle y hacer lista.append(pd.read_excel... y tu resultado seria una lista de `DataFrames` donde cada elemento de la `lista`, contiene un `DataFrame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu idea general de usar un ciclo `for` e ir generando variables con el nombre del archivo a las que asignarles cada DataFrame  es una posibilidad, pero crear variables de forma dinámica, aunque totalmente posible en Python, es por norma general mala idea y una mala práctica. La opción apropiada para estos casos suele ser usar un diccionario. La pregunta está íntimamente relacionada con:

- [Descomponer un dataframe en varios dataframes, uno por cada columna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/264761/15089)

Aunque en este caso los distintos DataFrames y su nombre asociado nos obligan a recorrer un directorio para buscar los archivos y obtener el nombre de la ruta. En tu caso concreto puedes hacer algo como:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd


PATH = 'C:/Users/PC/Documents/Programa peaje'

dataframes = {}
for xlsx_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH, '*.xlsx')):
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(xlsx_path))[0]
    frame = pd.read_excel(xlsx_path)
    dataframes[name] = frame
```

Esto buscará en el directorio `C:/Users/PC/Documents/Programa peaje` y seleccionará todo archivo con extensión xlsx, iterando sobre los mismos y generando un DataFrame para cada uno.

Con ello tendrás un diccionario de la forma:

> ```
> {'JULIO 2019':  pd.DataFrame
>  'JUNIO 2019':  pd.DataFrame
>  'MAYO 2019':   pd.DataFrame,
>   ...
> }
> ```

basta con usar la clave para acceder al DataFrame correspondiente:

```
>>> dataframes["JUNIO 2019"]
```